# Plagiarism on Questions

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, plagiarism

A while back I noticed a Question with code that I most certainly had seen before. I found it on a tutorial site. There was no attribution on the post. The post even referenced the code with "I have come up with java solution.." and "mine solution is". Since I couldn't be sure that the user wasn't the contributor of the code, I went through their other posts. I found one more Question where the code was missing attribution. This time to a different site with a different author. Now I was sure at least one of those posts wasn't written by the user, and I added a comment on the first post asking the user to add attribution. I checked to see if they were active, which they were. They seemed to ignore my comment and after a while I flagged the post for moderator attention.

I then went through all their posts and found two more. A total of 4 post. 2 of the posts had identical code, but not identical questions about the code. I didn't comment on the other 3 posts, as I didn't think it was necessary. I rechecked the posts about a week or so later to see if the user would give attribution, but they didn't, so I flagged the remaining 3.

Two of the flags were helpful, but the last two were declined:
[image]

I wasn't sure why. All 4 were Questions. I read the [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and sure enough it only mentions **answers**. That just doesn't seem right to me. Why would plagiarism be OK for Questions?

I've also read the post that is linked to from the "referencing" page: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered). This **doesn't** seem to be limited to answers, and I've "ticked off" the things I did with items in the linked post:

1. Yes. I checked. I double checked. I clicked on edit. I read the entire posts. No attribution.
2. I didn't think it was a minor incident. The entire block of code was (still is) copied line by line including comments. It wasn't a single incident.
3. I left a comment asking them to correct it. They ignored me. I don't think I was as diplomatic as the suggestions. I can't remember exactly what I wrote.
4. That's what I did. I went hunting for more. Reading this was a relief, as I wasn't sure if I had overstepped my bounds checking up on another user, myself being a regular low-rep user.

I also checked the date on the posts. They seemed more recent than the dates on the external source. I've since learned that my assumptions were correct, as a very patient person helped me find the original site on archive and it's dated June 13th 2011, making it a lot older than the Questions here.

I thought about fixing it (as suggested in **2**) for a short while, but I don't know for sure that the code was copied from this particular site, but even if it was, fixing the plagiarism isn't even tempting. There's a [copyright-notice](https://www.rgagnon.com/varia/copyrightnotice.txt) on the site, and I don't want my name in an edit that may at a later point link me to a copyright violation.

What item **2** (again from the other post) also says:

> If your flag gets declined, flag again and/or raise the issue on Meta.

I may be slightly OCD or something, but I really don't like my flags being declined. Especially not when I've put effort into them. There's also the feeling that I did something wrong, which I did by the first link, but not by the second.

Flagging again is a no-go for me. So.. here we are.

How am I suppose to handle it next time I notice plagarism on a Question?
Is it OK if I just pretend I don't see it?

Comment: Ps I suggested the [wording in the help center be changed to cover more than answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318005/323179) but it was (obviously) not acted on.

Comment: Side note: I disagree with reasoning of decline that plagiarism is not ok *only in answers*… Maybe as separate question here in support/clarification of @Laurel suggestion (as this seem to be mostly about declined flag).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I wish you hadn't deleted your post. It provides information that the moderator that handled the flag may agree with.

Comment: @Scratte moderators and everyone with 10K+ can see deleted posts just fine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know that. However I and roughly 11.5 mill other users can not. That's almost everyone that could benefit from the information.

Comment: @Scratte answer with -3 can hardly be considered useful information so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Just because your views aren't popular doesn't mean that they're not useful. In this context I find them very useful.

Comment: @Scratte but I mostly agree that my answer is not useful - there are tons of nearly identical posts on "why my flag was declined" with answers (often by diamond mods) "if it looks like you could do it yourself then flag will be declined even if mod performs the requested action". I had some fun writing it... but no particular reasons to keep it around.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But part of your argument was that I did not clearly point out that the source material had a copyright. Maybe the © was too subtle, and therefore I had not made it absolutely clear that neither I nor the community could do it ourselves. I did however notice that your Answer didn't address the last question in my Question, and wasn't very clear on what I should do the next time I see a similar situation.

Comment: is all code already written in this world, that can ever be written, i don't know, but sure is  for one problem there not that many solutions and solutions from one language surely can help in other languages. so it is no wonder that we find copies of one or other person.

Comment: @Scratte No, it is not what I tried to say. Indeed it is clear that you found source of the material along with copyright message. What we seem to disagree is whether the "this code has copyright" message clearly requests a particular action from a diamond mod - you believe "yes" and I see "no" - I don't see any action requested from a moderator. We really need feedback from some of the diamond mods here to clarify what *they* see as a main problem with these flags... but this particular question did not seem to get attention from any of them.

Comment: Can I have a link to the post?

Comment: @S.S.Anne Sure. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364156/saving-the-mails-in-outlook-message-format-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353806/polling-mailbox-after-every-10-minutes-through-java). They were deleted, so I can't see them anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through an extensive search, including:

- Searching the exact names of the questions, and
- Finding the user's profile and looking for them.

I didn't find these questions.

They have been deleted. [Samuel Liew ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) closed and deleted them both a week ago, so they likely saw this post and went back through your flag history to find them (or just did what I did and search).

Comment: Interesting :) I noticed that they were closed a while after I posted this.